# How to upload JavaScript File object to Cloudinary using node js api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, cloudinary

I need to upload a file to image server and i choose to go with [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/) from my node js api.
i installed the [npm package for cloudinary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudinary) and used the code as per their 
[api documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_and_video_upload)

here is my function which is making a http request call to upload image.

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;

function uploadProfilePic(req, res, next) {
   let file = (req && req.files.file) ? req.files.file : ''; // File object
   cloudinary.uploader.upload(file, function (error, result) {
      if (!error && result.url) {
         req.body.imageURL = result.url;
         next();
      }
      else {
         req.body.imageURL = '';
         next();
      }
   }).end(file.data);
}
```

Getting error "file.match is not a function".

how to upload image using file object on cloudinary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your question

> How to upload image using file object on cloudinary?

In order to upload File object to cloudinary, you can use upload_stream method instead of
upload. check documentation [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference).

Corrected your code:

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
function uploadProfilePic(req, res, next) {
   let file = (req && req.files.file) ? req.files.file : '';
   cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream({ resource_type: 'raw' }, function (error, result) {
      if (!error && result.url) {
         req.body.imageURL = result.url;
         next();
      }
      else {
         req.body.imageURL = '';
         next();
      }
   }).end(file.data);
}
```